# Simple regex - parse Firstname Lastname, sex (male,female), age or birth year

Tags: c#, regex

I have input text file:

> Max Smith m 20
>
> Dennis Bird m 20
>
> John Carter m 1970
>
> Elizabeth Cow f 1969

where

> Firstname Lastname sex age

or

> Firstname Lastname sex YearOfBirth

I need parse it and split to 3 elements using **C# and regex**: name, sex, age(or YearOfBirth)

Comment: Have you considered `String.Split`? No need for a regex here.

Comment: Your requirement is not a question. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, i tried. But i am newbee in regex and i can't parse "John Carter m 1970".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want "name, sex, age(or YearOfBirth)"
You still can use Regex for it, or [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx):

**Split solution:**

```
string line = "Max Smith m 20";
string[] words = line.Split(" ");

int nr = items[words.Length - 1]; 
//use number to determine age or year
string gender = items[words.Length - 2];
//string name = combine the leftover elements from the array
```

For the regex solution you have to take into account matching from right to left due names with extra spaces: `Max D. Smith jr. m 1978` (Example by Filburt)

Comment: May I introduce you to `Max D. Smith jr. m 1978`?

Comment: @Filburt: Indeed with string.split this would be hard (cutting and attaching the elements again). Regex would be more suitable then.